# Teams message card

Tags: windows, batch-file, microsoft-teams

I am trying to post message to Microsoft Teams channel using Windows batch script but I could not make use of the Teams message card formats. I am able to post messages using the below commands but as plain texts. Is there anyway in which I can make use of the Message card JSON formats ?

I also have some command line arguments which need to be used for the batch script so that the message displayed uses the same arguments.

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" --data "{\"@type\": \"ActionCard\",\"title\": \"New Lab %2 deployed successfully\", \"text\": \"Status is %3\"}" %1
```

The above command worked just fine. But doesnt satisfy my exact requirement which is described above.

I also created a seperate json file which was called as below and this worked fine but couldnt make use of command line arguments to format the JSON values.

```
curl --data @message.json webhook_url
```

message.json is as below

```html
{
   "summary":"New Lab deployed",
   "sections":[
      {
         "activityTitle":"A <b>new lab</b> has been added!"
      },
      {
         "title":"Details:",
         "facts":[
            {
               "name":"Lab Name",
               "value":"REPLACE"
            },
            {
               "name":"Status",
               "value":"REPLACE"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL is able to read data from file:

```
--data-binary "@message.json"
```

do not forget prepend AT sign to identify the doublequoted string is a filename, not a data itself.

Comment: that worked but I wanted to update the value in JSON file also

Comment: and some message cards didnt work. Was showing blank message too